# Why is my bmp writer not working?

Tags: c++, file-io, bmp, ostream

I'm trying to write a simple function that saves off some image data as bitmap. The data I'm generating is 3601 x 3601. I have verified in the debugger that all the data being passed to the function is correct. I have also verified that the pad size is as I would expect for a 24 bit BMP of width 3601 (padSize = 1).

The bitmap this creates is considerably larger then a bitmap I create with paint of the same dimensions meaning something here is writing too much data. I hex compared this file to a similarly sized bitmap and the headers were identical so I don't think my problem is there. I think my write command on the charbuffer must be writing more then expected, but I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

```
void SaveBMPData(string fname, unsigned char *data, int imgWid, int imgHei)
{

    ofstream file;
    file.open(fname.c_str(), std::ios::out);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        //string fname = "APnormal.bmp";
        cout << "INFO >> Saving BMP data: " << fname << "." << endl;

        //write header
        unsigned char fileinfo[14] = {
            'B', 'M', // magic
            0, 0, 0, 0, // size in bytes
            0, 0, // app data
            0, 0, // app data
            40 + 14, 0, 0, 0 // start of data offset
        };
        unsigned char info[40] = {
            40, 0, 0, 0, // info hd size
            0, 0, 0, 0, // width
            0, 0, 0, 0, // heigth
            1, 0, // number color planes
            24, 0, // bits per pixel
            0, 0, 0, 0, // compression is none
            0, 0, 0, 0, // image bits size
            0x13, 0x0B, 0, 0, // horz resoluition in pixel / m
            0x13, 0x0B, 0, 0, // vert resolutions (0x03C3 = 96 dpi, 0x0B13 = 72 dpi)
            0, 0, 0, 0, // #colors in pallete
            0, 0, 0, 0, // #important colors
        };    

        int w = imgWid;
        int h = imgHei;

        int padSize = (4 - ((w * 3) % 4)) % 4;
        int sizeData = w*h * 3 +h*padSize;
        int sizeAll = sizeData + sizeof(fileinfo) + sizeof(info);

        fileinfo[2] = (unsigned char)(sizeAll);
        fileinfo[3] = (unsigned char)(sizeAll >> 8);
        fileinfo[4] = (unsigned char)(sizeAll >> 16);
        fileinfo[5] = (unsigned char)(sizeAll >> 24);  

        info[4] = (unsigned char)(w);
        info[5] = (unsigned char)(w >> 8);
        info[6] = (unsigned char)(w >> 16);
        info[7] = (unsigned char)(w >> 24); 

        info[8] = (unsigned char) (h);
        info[9] = (unsigned char) (h >> 8);
        info[10] = (unsigned char)(h >> 16);
        info[11] = (unsigned char)(h >> 24);

        info[20] = (unsigned char)(sizeData);
        info[21] = (unsigned char)(sizeData >> 8);
        info[22] = (unsigned char)(sizeData >> 16);
        info[23] = (unsigned char)(sizeData >> 24);

        file.write((char*)fileinfo, sizeof(fileinfo));
        file.write((char*)info, sizeof(info));

        unsigned char *charbuffer = new unsigned char[w * 3 + padSize];

        for (int y = 0; y<h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x<w; x++)
            {
                unsigned char red = data[(x + y*imgWid) * 3];
                unsigned char green = data[(x + y*imgWid) * 3 + 1];
                unsigned char blue = data[(x + y*imgWid) * 3 + 2];
                charbuffer[x * 3    ] = blue;
                charbuffer[x * 3 + 1] = green;
                charbuffer[x * 3 + 2] = red;

            }
            file.write((char *)(void*)charbuffer, w*3+padSize);

        }
        file.close();
        delete [] charbuffer;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "can't read file.\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file in binary mode, otherwise any pixel component with a value of 0x0a will result in a write to the file of 0x0d 0x0a.

```
file.open(fname.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: Good point if that opens by default in text mode :) One way to also determine is use **long pos = file.tellp();** after each write to tell where it is in the file and if it wrote more than you expected.

Comment: This was the correct fix thanks so much!!! This fixed my problem!!! you are a gentlemen and a saint!

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the bitmap from paint as a 24 bit bmp?

I would highly suggest getting some code on the internet such as here: http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html and looking at/using that code.

I would avoid using arrays with values and comments (info, fileinfo) and use real concrete structs to define properties.

Your problem should be easy to figure out but IMO you are better off using some code already written since this has been done *so* many times.

Comment: Unfortunately for me I can't use an external library. My header I believe is correct as if I change the data around to set rgb to the same valies in the incoming data it writes correctly. Only when img data is an array of random variables does it get confused and render too much information. Thanks for the link. I'll look into it.

Comment: What are your file sizes? I'd expect 3601x3601x3 = 38901603 + padding (3601*1) + header info to be roughly around that size.

Comment: The correct file size should be 38,905,258 My file is working out to be 38,926,864. which works out to be 6 extra bytes per row.